# How can I tell [G]vim where to look for python26.dll?

Tags: python, vim

I have a version of Vim compiled with python 2.6 support enabled ([from here](http://www.gooli.org/blog/)). however vim cannot find the python26.dll.

```
:version confirms +python/dyn
:version and gvim.exe confirms DYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL="python26.dll"
echo PATH confirms python26.dll is in the search path.
    (both c:\windows\system32, and C:\python26)
```

What could I be missing? Did I skip something silly?

**UPDATE** Nevermind. I just saw it. Vim is x86 and python is x64. Sorry to waste your time. Score 1 for [Dependancy Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: Could you please share how exactly you used Dependency Walker to solve this? I am not sure if having python2.7 64bit installed at the same time as python3 32bit causes a problem or not. As my vim can't find python either right now...

Comment: drozzy: This was a while ago, but if I remember correctly there was an error listed in one of the panes suggesting the python.dll was being found but couldn't be loaded due to bitness mismatch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be sure that any dll you try to load is compiled for the same architecture as the exe. 
e.g. If you have x86 Vim installed. Make sure that the python dll you are loading is not x64, or vice-versa.